# IMAGE VIEW ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, layout

I have a doubt. While working on an App , I came across this query.

When an Imageview1(smaller size) is dragged and dropped on to Imageview2(bigger size), how to make Imageview1 (fit the area of imageview2), that is, enlarge the Imageview1 automatically to the size of Imageview2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing something so twisted, you can try a simpler solution like:

```
ImageView2.setImageDrawable(ImageView1.getDrawable());
ImageView1.setVisibility(INVISIBLE); //GONE could be used too, depending on the situation
```

Overwriting ImageView2 would involve many other operations like moving ImageView1 inside the layout, setting new LayoutParams, etc.

*EDIT*

Use this:

```
ImageView1.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap src = ImageView1.getDrawingCache();

BitmapDrawable destDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, ImageView2.getWidth(), ImageView2.getHeight(), false));
ImageView2.setImageDrawable(destDrawable);
```

In general, it is not a good practice to have views cover other views.

Comment: Actually the aim is to let the user drag the image and place it so that it takes that area that is so that it looks like a puzzle. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain the problem in a bit more detail? Maybe using a gif or a matrix showing the states?

Comment: SImple, 2 image views. one imageview is an empty space with bigger size and the second imageview is a smaller one. The smaller needs to fit the size of bigger one when dragg and dropped. I had finished the code for drag and drop but the smaller one needs to fit the larger one

Comment: getting an error ->  android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: check this I tried                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                if(bitmap == bitmap2)
                {

                    image1.setImageDrawable(bird1.getDrawable());
                    bird1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

                }

Comment: Error ->  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Comment: The code can only work if the original bitmap is already on the screen. You need to put the code inside an event listener eg. an OnClickListener. For drag and drop, use it when the image has been dropped.

Comment: This works for one to one imageview, what if there are more than 2 imageviews , and we need to compare only those that are dragged and dropped on. This logic only works for one.

Comment: Attach an OnTouchListener to the ImageView that has to be dragged, and build the cache in ACTION_DOWN. Store the resulting bitmap in a class variable, not a local one. Then use this to set the image in the target ImageView.

Comment: bird1.buildDrawingCache(); Bitmap src = ImageView1.getDrawingCache();                       BitmapDrawable destDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src,
image1.getWidth(),        image1.getHeight(), false));
BitmapDrawable destDrawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src,
image2.getWidth(),        image2.getHeight(), false));
                        image1.setImageDrawable(destDrawable); 
 imageview2.setImageDrawable(destDrawable1);                         break;

Comment: I used the above code but on touch is getting fit into both the image views

Answer (score 0):

When you do the drag action try this

```
ImageView.ScaleType(FIT_XY);
```

Comment: you are referring to which imageview

Comment: no, it isnt working showing an error. So I coded imageView1.ScaleType(FIT_XY);